# Cannot ping gateway or access control panel on WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm having some trouble pinging anything on my network using WiFi. I have a Netgear WNDR3700v5 router and i'm using both 2.4GHz and 5GHz. When I'm connected with my laptop to my 2.4GHz network I'm not able to ping anything on the network or access my router, however, when I'm connected to the 5GHz network I can ping everything and access my router.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Thanks!

Comment: What are your IPs when connected to 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq They're always 10.0.0.x

Comment: Seems like you have some sort of custom configuration going on. It would be useful to post what you have changed.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq The router gave this IP by default

Comment: That's strange, Netgear usually defaults to the 192.168.x.x range.

Comment: True, but my first router is using the 192.168.x.x range so the netgear router changed it automatically